# I am actually working on an ML problem and I have some date columns that contains just dates in plain integer format and I want to convert it

Tags: python

I am actually working on an ML problem and I have some date columns that contain just dates in plain integer format and I want to convert it.
Like: 20200225 into a date_time format...2020-02-25
I am using python
Any suggestions on how to work my way out.

Comment: Convert the integer to a string with `str(myintdate)` and convert that to a datetime with `datetime.datetime.strptime()`.

Comment: Your date is in an integer format like 20220810, or is it an integer Unix timestamp format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this

```
from datetime import datetime

date_string = "20200625"

print("date_string =", date_string)
print("type of date_string =", type(date_string))

date_object = datetime.strptime(date_string, "%Y%m%d")

print("date_object =", date_object)

print("type of date_object =", type(date_object))
```

**sample output:**

2022-02-10 08:50:24.100195

date_string = 20200625

type of date_string = <class 'str'>

date_object = 2020-06-25 00:00:00

type of date_object = <class 'datetime.datetime'>

Comment: I would complete the answer by adding: `datetime.strftime(date_object, "%Y-%m-%d")`, to give the date in the final format asked in the question

Comment: Thanks that solved my problem.✌️

Answer (score 0):

I think this should be good for what your asking

```
import datetime
today=datetime.datetime.today()
print(today)
```

Comment: i have used all those things nothing seems to work, I have is a date in integer format, the complete date...that means the date is not in string format its like 20200125 which I want to convert to --->2020-01-25

Comment: this does put it in the format your looking for (yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.6 digits of millisecond)